# Printing 0's instead of keyboard input

Tags: java

So the program is supposed to allow the user to input 10 scores and the print those scores in ascending order on the following line. For some reason it allows me to input the scores, but the following line is just filled with 0s instead of sorting the input in ascending order. I'm  not sure why, but any input would be helpful.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out
            .println("Enter up to 35 scores between 0 and 100, -1 to stop:");

    int[] score = new int[35];
    int count = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    String scores = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < score.length; i++) {
        score[i] = keyboard.nextInt();
        if (score[i] >= 0) {

            scores = scores + score[i] + "     ";
            count++;
            sum = sum + score[i];
        } else
            i = score.length + 1;

    }

    for (int i = 1; i < score.length; i++) {
        int x;
        int temp;

        x = score[i];
        temp = score[i];
        for (x = i - 1; x >= 0 && score[x] > temp; x--) {
            score[x + 1] = score[x];
        }
        score[x + 1] = temp;
    }

    System.out.printf("The %d scores you entered are: \n%s", count, scores);
    System.out.println();
    System.out.printf("The %d scored sorted in nondecreasing order are:\n",
            count);
    int k=1;
    for (k=1; k <= count; k++) {
        if (k % 11 == 0) {
            System.out.println();
        } else {
            System.out.printf("%5d", score[k]);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
        if (i % 11 == 0) {
            System.out.println();
        } else {
            System.out.printf("%5d", score[i]);
        }

        for (int j = 1; j < count; j++) {
            if (Integer.compare(score[i], score[j]) < 0) {
                int temp = score[i];
                score[i] = score[j];
                score[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: An article about Java debugging in Eclipse: http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseDebugging/article.html.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with comment about learning to debug. The way you have written your code, it is apparent that you are very beginner so here is the answer to help you. To answer your question, you have several logical mistakes in your program.

You can simply use break to exit out of the first for loop. so in the else statement just write break; instead of i = score.length + 1;

Next... mistake is that you are sorting entire array... However as you may have entered only 5 or 6 elements before entering -1, your first 5 or 6 elements will have values and all other values in that score array as 0. If you sort the entire array, you will obviously be going to bring 0's to the front and actual scores to the back of the array. This is the answer for your question. Sort from i = 0 to i < count. This will fix some of your issues, but you have many more issues.

There are several other issues. I hope you will be able to debug and find out.

Comment: It is a better idea to use a ArrayList versus using an array, so that the size will be the actual amount of scores entered, and there will be no need to cap the scores at 35.

Comment: Yes, if I write this program, that is what I would use.